# error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

Tags: mysql

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -u root
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("newrootpassword") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

I've tried the above to no avail.

I was editing the `/etc/my.cnf` file, and when I noticed this issue I reverted to the back up I made prior to editing it.

The issue persists.  What could the problem be?

These are the commands I ran that I believe may have caused the issue:

```
mysql> update db set Host='myip' where Db='mydb';
mysql> update user set Host='myip' where user='root';
```

Note that I have no issues accessing the phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Host set to `%` or `localhost` in the User table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql> update db set Host='localhost' where Db='mydb';
mysql> update user set Host='localhost' where user='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Host must be `localhost` if you connect to `localhost`, not your IP and not your servers ip.

You can also use the wildcard `%`.

Comment: Fixed.  Oh god... Thank you soooo much...  Now..  How can I connect to the remote DB (in production) from my computer?

Comment: @user3817533 this would also work with `%` or if you connect to `db.your.domain` this is what you put in `Host`. But if you can reach the network at all also depends on firewall and config like `bind-address`.

Comment: I'm working locally on a project.  `$db = new mysqli('myip', 'root', 'mypass', 'mydb');` isn't working.  What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: I already told you the most common.. look for `bind-address` and firewall, iptables, ....